# bash profile not opening nano editor

Tags: server, bash, sudo, nano

im wondering why my Ubuntu 18.04 (LTS) x64 is unresposive to sudo commands.

im trying to configure env variables for GO and my command to get in to nano is `nano ~/.zshrc`

nothing happens and doesnt ask me to log in. Has anyone had this before?

Comment: I'm confused - you mention "sudo commands" but the command you show, `nano ~/.zshrc` doesn't use sudo (and shouldn't - don't edit files in your own home directory as root). Also `~/.zshrc` is not a "bash profile". Please [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the user you are using to sudoers?

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-user-to-sudoers-in-ubuntu/

If you are on the desktop version you can do that through a UI

[https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-sudo-user-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux#:~:text=Create%20a%20sudo%20user%20using%20GUI,-Using%20your%20graphical&text=Next%20navigate%20to%20About%2D%3EUsers,Hit%20Add%20user..](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-create-sudo-user-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux#:%7E:text=Create%20a%20sudo%20user%20using%20GUI,-Using%20your%20graphical&text=Next%20navigate%20to%20About%2D%3EUsers,Hit%20Add%20user..).